# Mule: Interface binding for different components, how to avoid duplication?

Tags: java, spring, mule, esb

We have the following mule flow:

```
<flow name="mule-flow-1">
   <component>
       <spring-object bean="springBean_1"/>
        <binding interface="com.acme.EmailService" method="send">
             <vm:outbound-endpoint path="send-email" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        </binding>
     </component> 
</flow>
```

but right now we want to introduce new flow, with new Spring bean which uses the same `EmailService.send` method, so, we can do it as:

```
<flow name="mule-flow-2">
   <component>
       <spring-object bean="springBean_2"/>
        <binding interface="com.acme.EmailService" method="send">
             <vm:outbound-endpoint path="send-email" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        </binding>
     </component> 
</flow>
```

As you can see, we bound `EmailService.send` method twice in two different flows and it is pure code duplication.

Is it possible to bind `EmailService.send` method somewhere in common place and just use ref in `mule-flow-1` and `mule-flow-2`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use subflow? Define your component there and then use flow-ref in any flow you want to reuse it.

```
<sub-flow name="mule-flow-send">
 <component>
   <spring-object bean="springBean_1"/>
    <binding interface="com.acme.EmailService" method="send">
         <vm:outbound-endpoint path="send-email" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
    </binding>
 </component> 
</sub-flow>
```

and then reusing:

```
<flow name="mule-flow-1">
  <flow-ref name="mule-flow-send" doc:name="mule-flow-send"/>
</flow>
<flow name="mule-flow-2">
  <flow-ref name="mule-flow-send" doc:name="mule-flow-send"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: The problem is: We are using `springBean_1` and `springBean_2`, bot of them are using the same method `send` of `EmailService` interface, so your solution is slightly incorrect.